# Graphing Applet is not running on Web browser

Tags: applet, browser

I got the source code from JFreeCharts of DynamicTimeSeriesCollection display.

It works fine when I run it as a simple java application, but then I wanted it as applet.

So I made the Applet code, and inserted all the code in start(), paint() and init() functions.

This runs well when I do "Run File", but when I try opening the generated HTML page on a webbrowser (Java SE 6 enabled) it gives a blank screen. I am using Netbeans 7.0.

The code is as follows,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.time.DynamicTimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.time.Second;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GraphTest extends JApplet {

    private static final String TITLE = "ECG of the Patient";
    private static final String START = "Start";
    private static final String STOP = "Stop";
    private static final float MINMAX = 100;
    private static final int COUNT = 2 * 60;
    private static final int FAST = 100;
    private static final int SLOW = FAST * 5;
    private Timer timer;
    // private Object random;
    //private static final Random random = new Random();
    ReadAFile file_reader = new ReadAFile();
    byte[] values = file_reader.Readfile();
    float[] temp = new float[120];

    public GraphTest() {
        //super(title);
        final DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset =
                new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, COUNT, new Second());
        dataset.setTimeBase(new Second(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2011));

        dataset.addSeries(temp, 0, "ECG Plot");
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);

        final JButton run = new JButton(STOP);
        run.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
                if (STOP.equals(cmd)) {
                    timer.stop();
                    run.setText(START);
                } else {
                    timer.start();
                    run.setText(STOP);
                }
            }
        });

        final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
        combo.addItem("Fast");
        combo.addItem("Slow");
        combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if ("Fast".equals(combo.getSelectedItem())) {
                    timer.setDelay(FAST);
                } else {
                    timer.setDelay(SLOW);
                }
            }
        });

        this.add(new ChartPanel(chart), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        btnPanel.add(run);
        btnPanel.add(combo);
        this.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        timer = new Timer(FAST, new ActionListener() {

            float[] newData = new float[1];
            int i = 0;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                newData[0] = values[i];
                dataset.advanceTime();
                dataset.appendData(newData);
                i++;

            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Initialization method that will be called after the applet is loaded
     * into the browser.
     */
    @Override
    public void init() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            private String TITLE;
            //  this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            @Override
            public void run() {

                //DTSCTest demo = new DTSCTest(TITLE);
                // DTSCTest demo = new DTSCTest(TITLE);
                // pack();
                //RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen();
                //RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
                setVisible(true);
                //demo.start();
            }
        });
        // TODO start asynchronous download of heavy resources
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
        final JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
                TITLE, "hh:mm:ss", "Magnitude", dataset, true, true, false);
        final XYPlot plot = result.getXYPlot();
        ValueAxis domain = plot.getDomainAxis();
        domain.setAutoRange(true);
        ValueAxis range = plot.getRangeAxis();
        range.setRange(-MINMAX, MINMAX);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Here is another java file that is called by this class

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadAFile {

    float[] datavalues = new float[300];

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public byte[] Readfile() {
        StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            // use buffering, reading one line at a time
            // FileReader always assumes default encoding is OK!
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Desktop/Mytest.txt"));

            try {
                String line = null; // not declared within while loop
                /*
                 * readLine is a bit quirky : it returns the content of a line
                 * MINUS the newline. it returns null only for the END of the
                 * stream. it returns an empty String if two newlines appear in
                 * a row.
                 */
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    contents.append(line);
                }
            } finally {
                input.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) { System.out.println("Exception coming ");
        }
        byte[] finalarray = new byte[contents.length()];
        for (int ch = 0; ch < contents.length(); ++ch) {
            char co = contents.charAt(ch);
            int j = (int) co;
            finalarray[ch] = (byte) j;

        }
        return finalarray;
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 0):

It may look like I repeat myself (if you look at other answers of mine), but: **Never override the `paint()` method in Swing!**

If you really need to paint something, override `paintComponent()`. But in your case, you should simply put one of JFreeChart's components inside the applet (what you did in the constructor), and be done.

(Just for completeness: All GUI related stuff should be done in the AWT event dispatch thread, like using `EventQueue.invokeLater` (or SwingUtilities.invokeLater). The Applet's constructor will not be invoked in this thread, which means that you should not do the GUI initializations in the constructor. Better put this in your `invokeLater` called from the init method.)